# ImportError: cannot import name Style in Odoo 10 - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10, postgresql-9.6

from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font, Alignment, Border, Side
ImportError: cannot import name Style

i have already install Style but still error display.

Answer (score 0):

change **Style** to **NamedStyle**

```
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
```

Style is no longer available in the new versions